# How to mangle and then demangle a function during LLVM pass?

Tags: c++, llvm, compiler-optimization

I have an LLVM pass used to rename functions. Given some source file `file.cc`, I generate LLVM bitcode as follows:

`clang -c -o foo.bc -emit-llvm foo.cc`.

I'd like to run an LLVM pass over `foo.bc` and rename all globals, functions and aliases so that I can output the transformed bitcode to a new file `file_renamed.bc`, and then link `file.bc` and `file_renamed.bc` into a single file, `file_linked.bc`.

One of my issues I encountered is that simply doing `F.setName(F.getName() + "_renamed")`, will add the suffix after the **mangled** name returned by `F.getName()`.

Another issue: I have  a function `demangle(const std::string &Name)` below that successfully demangles `Name`, but I'm having trouble re-mangling that name.

If there is a better way to rename identifiers in LLVM bitcode, or otherwise link two instances of the same bitcode but still be able to uniquely identify the functions and global variables in each version, feel free to suggest it in your answer.

Here is my LLVM pass. Note that I'm using LLVM 3.4 (it is a dependency for the project I'm working on.)

**Headers**

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <cxxabi.h>
#include <memory>

#include "llvm/Pass.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Function.h"
#include "llvm/Support/raw_ostream.h"
#include "llvm/ADT/STLExtras.h"
#include "llvm/ADT/SmallString.h"
#include "llvm/ADT/SmallVector.h"
#include "llvm/ADT/StringRef.h"
#include "llvm/ADT/Twine.h"
#include "llvm/IR/DerivedTypes.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Module.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Type.h"
#include "llvm/IR/TypeFinder.h"
#include "llvm/Transforms/IPO.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Argument.h"
#include "llvm/IR/GlobalValue.h"
#include "llvm/IR/DataLayout.h"
#include "llvm/Target/Mangler.h"
```

**Code**

```
using namespace llvm;

namespace {

  struct FunctionRename : public ModulePass {
    static char ID; // Pass identification

    FunctionRename() : ModulePass(ID) {}

    bool runOnModule(Module &M) override {

      // Rename all globals and references to them
      for (auto it = M.global_begin(); it != M.global_end(); ++it)
      {...}

      // Rename all aliases and references to them
      for (auto it = M.alias_begin(); it != M.alias_end(); ++it)
      {...}

      // Rename all functions and references to them
      for (auto &F : M)
      {
        StringRef Name = F.getName();
        if (F.isDeclaration())
          continue;

        std::string demangled_name = demangle(Name.str());
        std::string new_name = rename(demangled_name);
        F.setName(mangle(new_name, &F));
        F.setLinkage(GlobalValue::WeakAnyLinkage);
      }
      return true;
    }

    std::string demangle(const std::string &Name)
    {
      int status;
      char* demangled_name = NULL;
      char* cstr_name = new char[Name.length() + 1];
      strcpy(cstr_name, Name.c_str());
      demangled_name = __cxxabiv1::__cxa_demangle(cstr_name, NULL, NULL, &status);
      if (status != 0)
      {
        errs() << "Demangling operation failed:\n";
        switch (status)
        {...}
        exit(-1);
      }
      std::string s(demangled_name);
      return s;
    }

    std::string rename(std::string &Name)
    {
      std::string search_str = std::string("(");
      std::string suffix_str = std::string("_renamed");
      size_t i = Name.find_first_of(search_str);
      if (i == std::string::npos)
        Name.append(suffix_str);
      else
        Name.insert(i, suffix_str);
      return Name;
    }

    /* PROBLEMATIC FUNCTION */
    std::string mangle(const std::string &Name, const GlobalValue *GV)
    {
      SmallString<256> MangledName(StringRef(Name));

      Mangler m;
      m.getNameWithPrefix((SmallVectorImpl<char>&) MangledName, GV, false, true);
      Twine T;
      StringRef S = T.toStringRef((SmallVectorImpl<char>&) MangledName);
      return S.str();
    }
  };
}

// Register Pass
char FunctionRename::ID = 0;
static RegisterPass<FunctionRename> X("functionrename", "Function Rename Pass");
```

Comment: I think your `demangle` function is also wrong. It demangles using C++ ABI library LLVM was compiled against, and bitcode may be produced by compiler with different C++ ABI.

Comment: If I remember correctly the "Mangler" included in LLVM is not a C++ mangler but a C mangler that typically just adds a "_" to symbol names to distinguish C symbols from assembly symbols, if you want to mangle C++ you may need to link to clang libraries corresponding to the clang you used for generating the bitcode.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot easily mangle the C++ identifiers just from string. You need to have proper C++ AST. In fact, I don't see why you'd need that mangle / demangle thing at all. Since you're working at LLVM IR level you should not bother with language details (like original unmangled name) at all.